# Conditions in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website on PHP which works as "appointment management System". I have 5 Doctors in my clinic. I have added them in list (web). Now when a patient comes in clinic i fill a form which contains (Name, Add, Phone number, Appointment with Dr.(Selecting from a list), appointment date and time. **Now my Question is how can i restrict this form if we have already an appointment is booked on same date and same time like 1-Oct-2015 and start time 2pm to 3pm with a patient. Form can not duplicate/override previous appointment and gives me notification that in this timing already an appointment is fixed with doctor 1.** ??? plz help

Comment: You will receive a better response if you show the code you have tried so far and preferably a table schema

Comment: A clue : If statement

Comment: I know if condition will be used but how i don't know :-(

Comment: You should applied form validation with ajax call to check date and time entered by user to get appointment.

Comment: for better understand please provide code. we help you..

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided anything code wise to show whatever you have or have tried at the moment, my answer will be very straightforward: check your database for a duplicate record with that same date and time range before saving.